# How do i solve the connect ETIMEDOUT issue with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, mern

When i try to run a request through POSTMAN to send a mail, I get an error

```
dotenv.config();

const { AUTH_EMAIL, AUTH_PASSWORD, APP_URL } = process.env;

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.office365.com",
  auth: {
    user: AUTH_EMAIL,
    pass: AUTH_PASSWORD,
  },
});
```

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.98.16.194:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '52.98.16.194',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}
POST /users/request-passwordreset 404 22197.939 ms - 53
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: If you look at `AUTH_EMAIL, AUTH_PASSWORD`, with say, `console.log`, do they have the values you expect?